# Convert accented characters into ascii character

Tags: r, transliteration

What is the optimal way to to remove German (or French) accents from a vector of 16 million string variables.

e.g., 'Sjögren's syndrome' into 'Sjogren's syndrome'

Converstion of single character into a single character is better then transliteration such as

ä => ae    ö => oe  ü => ue.

e.g., using regular expression would be one option but is there something better (R package for this)?

`gsub('ü','u',gsub('ö','o',"Sjögren's syndrome ( über) "))`

There are SO solutions for non-R platforms but not a good one for R.

Comment: See the answer to this post: [stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r

Comment: See the answer to this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699271/force-character-vector-encoding-from-unknown-to-utf-8-in-r

Answer (score 29):

Use `iconv` to convert to ASCII with transliteration (if supported):

```
iconv(c("über","Sjögren's"),to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "uber"      "Sjogren's"
```

Comment: for accented characters, e.g.`é`, this will result in something that looks like `'e`. Run this command over the output vector of the operation above: `out <- gsub("\\'", '', out)`

Answer (score 29):

One of the linked answers suggest

```
library(stringi)
stri_trans_general("Zażółć gęślą jaźń", "Latin-ASCII")

[1] "Zazolc gesla jazn"
```