# R function not working when imported

Tags: r, import

I am writing some functions on sublime text which I want to use on jupyter notebook or Rstudio.
the function works fine on Sublime but the output from it in jupyter or Rstudio is not good.

the function:

```
normalize <- function(str, tobereplaced = c('à','â','ä'), replacements = c('a','a','a') ){
        for (i in 1:length(tobereplaced)){
            str <- gsub( tobereplaced[i], replacements[i], str)
        }
        return(str)
    }
```

When executing :

```
normalize("àâä")
```

**output sublime :**

```
Warning message:
Warning messages:
[1] "aaa"
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

**output jupyter & Rstudio :**

```
'àâä'
```

Can someone please help ? (I imported the R file containing the function with `source()`)

**Edit** : The problem occurs only when importing the R file containing the function. When I define the function locally it does work fine.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem in RStudio. Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you Z.Lin the problem occurs when importing the function only.

Comment: I saved the script as a R file in 3 different encodings (ANSI, unicode, UTF-8) & sourced each version into RStudio. They all worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help, still not working on my end, I'll give it another try

Comment: You may wish to check out the solution here. The use case seems similar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898175/8449629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The problem was due to the encoding from the jupyter notebook.

one way to solve this is to do the following:

```
source("file.R", encoding = "UTF-8" )
```

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
> normalize <- function(str, tobereplaced = c('à','â','ä'), replacements = c('a','a','a') ){
+   for (i in 1:length(tobereplaced)){
+     str <- gsub( tobereplaced[i], replacements[i], str)
+   }
+   return(str)
+ }
> normalize("àâä")
[1] "aaa"
>
```

I ran your code in Rstudio version 1.0.153 it working fine ...

Comment: The problem occurs only when I import the function into Rstudio or Jupyter, if defined locally it does work fine for me as well