# Edit the 'term' object in glm() function

Tags: r

I have an object called `modelTrain` generated by the `glm()` function. This object has several other objects like: `coefficients`, `formula`, `terms` etc..

```
 modelTrain<- glm(Def90Adj ~ .-1,data=base,family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

I have to change the name of some variables keeping the values used for prediction. One of objects in `modelTrain` is of type 'call' (or 'language')

Its content is as follows:

```
attr(,"variables")
list(Def90Adj, `AveLncerLimiteRatio(0,1.04]`, `AveLncerLimiteRatio(1.04,3.96]`, 
`AveLncerLimiteRatio(11.4,40.3]`, `AveLncerLimiteRatio(3.96,11.4]`, 
`AveLncerLimiteRatio(40.3, Inf]`, `Ave6mEvoluçãoAvencerRatio(0, Inf]`, 
`Ven6mEvoluçãoVencidoRatio(0.0001, Inf]`, `Ven6mEvoluçãoVencidoRatio[-Inf,-0.0001]`, 
`Avvencer(0,1.01e+04]`, `AVBenNegAVenRatio(0, Inf]`, 
`AVeNnNociAVenRatio(0, Inf]`, LimDummy, VencidoDummy, 
PrejuDummy, AVedncerDummy)
```

I want to change the names with special characters like `"Ven6mEvoluçãoVencidoRatio(0.0001, Inf]"` to `"Ven6mEvolucaoVencidoRatio(0.0001, Inf]"` (without the special characters)

I tried copying the current content without the special characters

```
attr(modelTrain$terms, "variables") <- list((Def90Adj,AveLncerLimiteRatio(0,1.04]....
```

But it throws the error:

> "Def90Adj" was not found.

Comment: this might be easier to do to the data prior to adding it to the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute-force method uses `quote()`:

```
L1 <- quote(list(Def90Adj, `AveLncerLimiteRatio(0,1.04]`, `AveLncerLimiteRatio(1.04,3.96]`, 
`AveLncerLimiteRatio(11.4,40.3]`, `AveLncerLimiteRatio(3.96,11.4]`, 
`AveLncerLimiteRatio(40.3, Inf]`, `Ave6mEvolucaoAvencerRatio(0, Inf]`, 
`Ven6mEvolucaoVencidoRatio(0.0001, Inf]`, `Ven6mEvolucaoVencidoRatio[-Inf,-0.0001]`, 
`Avvencer(0,1.01e+04]`, `AVBenNegAVenRatio(0, Inf]`, 
`AVeNnNociAVenRatio(0, Inf]`, LimDummy, VencidoDummy, 
PrejuDummy, AVedncerDummy))
```

To do this programatically, you need something like:

```
for (i in 2:length(L1)) {
    L1[[i]] <- substitute(x,list(x=gsub("V","v",deparse(L1[[i]]))))
}
```

(this example just changes uppercase V to lowercase v ...)

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610319/convert-accented-characters-into-ascii-character) suggest that `stringi::stri_trans_general(x,"Latin-ASCII")` will convert accented characters to their non-accented analogues ...