# Can't use iconv to convert accented characters in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have this dataset:

```
datasample <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                         prod = c("__eggs", 
                                  "fresh <br> turkey", 
                                  "meat tosón"))
```

And I want to clean the `prod` variable. In this case to extract the `<br>` tag and to convert the "tosón" text to "toson". I read in SO the solution for the accented characters: [Convert accented characters into ascii character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610319/convert-accented-characters-into-ascii-character) so I tried this code:

```
data <- datasample %>% 
  mutate(prod = str_replace(prod, "__", ""),
         prod = str_replace(prod, "<br>", ""),
         prod = iconv(prod, to="ASCII//TRANSLIT"))
```

But this is the result:

```
data

  id              prod
1  1              eggs
2  2 fresh <br> turkey
3  3        meat tosón
```

Please, do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When I run the code the value is changed in the output. I cannot replicate the behavior you are seeing. Are you looking at the output of the `mutate()` call? Or are you looking at the original `datasample` value. `mutate()` will not update the existing data.frame, it will return a new one. What OS are you using? What version of R are you running?

Comment: Hello @MrFlick, I changed the code to see if the data.frame updating worked, but I have the same result. I use a Mac, and the version is 4.1.0

Comment: @Alexis I'm on Mac, but I get the correct result. Unsure why this is happening. Voting to close because it's not reproducible